# Why the generated client code has header file missing

Tags: c, openapi, openapi-generator-cli

I have written an OAS file and I have generated client code via `openapi-generator-cli`
command as below

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g c -i EPS_IMS.yaml
```

The above command has generated the code, now when I try to compile the code, I am getting below compilation error

```
In file included from /home/ocadmin/openAPI/SUBA_tmp/model/_suba_integrated_get_200_response_one_of.h:18,
                 from /home/ocadmin/openAPI/SUBA_tmp/model/_suba_integrated_get_200_response.h:19,
                 from /home/ocadmin/openAPI/SUBA_tmp/model/_suba_integrated_get_200_response.c:4:
/home/ocadmin/openAPI/SUBA_tmp/model/integratedconfig_properties.h:18:10: fatal error: integer_.h: No such file or directory
 #include "integer_.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I did a cross check, the mentioned header file is not generated. so, my doubt is how do I solve such issues where file is included without generation.